# Isolated RTD sensor

Tags: isolation, rtd

I need to read a Heatsink temperature with 5KV isolation.

how is it possible?

are there isolated temperature sensors ? or
shall I design a board for it to isolate the output signals?

Comment: I'd design a board with digital isolation and an isolated power supply.

Comment: It's not a Pt100, rather thermocouple, but it seems very decent built: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000224124485.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1436ae13yGAuIl&algo_pvid=80f56c64-f4f1-4b68-9217-c9ec1789ff4e&algo_expid=80f56c64-f4f1-4b68-9217-c9ec1789ff4e-26&btsid=0ab6f82c15970537481267855e7f7c&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: PT100 isolated: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33016693183.html?spm=2114.12010615.8148356.4.2c8c54b0gGGTSo

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to design a small RTD reader, and optically isolate the digital signal back to your MCU. In the case of a HV PSU, I've done this using an NTC and analog converter, with isolated COMS back to the MCU.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bond a thin-film RTD sensor to a piece of alumina or Macor and screw or bond that to the heatsink.

If your heat sink has HV AC on it, you may have a significant additional problem no matter how you do  the isolation because of capacitive coupling.